# Extending Kahler metric from a neighborhood of a divisor to the whole manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective variety with an ample line bundle $L$, and let $D\subset X$ be a smooth divisor. Suppose in an analytic neighborhood $U$ of $D$ there is a Kahler form $\omega$ such that the class of $\omega|_D$ in $H^{1,1}(D)$ equals $c_1(L)$. How to prove that there exists an even smaller analytic neighborhood $U'\subset U$ of $D$ such that $\omega$ can be extended from $U'$ to a Kahler form on whole $X$?

Comment: If $D$ be simple normal crossing divisor and take $D=\sum_{j=1}^n D_j$ where $D_j=\{\sigma_j=0\}$ , then $\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar\partial (-\log (|\sigma_j|^2))$ extends
to a smooth real (1,1)-form on the whole $X$

Comment: See http://www.numdam.org/article/AFST_2014_6_23_4_893_0.pdf in Kahler current sense and not as Kahler form

Comment: Hassan, thanks for the link! It is not far from what I am looking for

Comment: I deleted my original "answer". Will think about it later.

Comment: You may see Skoda-El Mir extension theorem also which is related to your question but in Kahler current sense and not smooth Kahler form

Comment: See Theorem 4.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609617.pdf

Comment: Thanks Hassan, I already found this paper thanks to your first link. I think this proof can indeed be modified to give an answer to my question.